# brew install libyaml ERROR

Tags: installation, homebrew, libyaml

```
$ brew install libyaml
==> Downloading http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libyaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.4
==> make install
Warning: Could not link libyaml. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link libyaml'
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.4: 7 files, 336K, built in 9 seconds
```

OS X 10.8.2
how do I fix this problem?
what should I do ?

Answer (score 33):

Start with `brew doctor` which will show you errors with your brew setup.

You might see something like this: "Warning: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig isn't writable."

It will give you the advice that: "You should probably chown /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig".

This means:   `sudo chown {your-user-name} /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

Then you will need to link the files with this: `brew link libyaml`

If this does not work hopefully the output of `brew doctor` will give you enough to continue the search.